# Wordpress - Managing media in bespoke plugin

Tags: wordpress

I have built a wordpress plugin that stores information about products. It uses its own bespoke tables. The idea is that this acts as a master product list and I am using wordpress as a simple CRUD for now.

We want to start uploading photos to be linked to the products we have added and I am wondering what is the best way to go about this.

Rather than building an upload tool in the plugin, I was thinking of simply using the media library to upload the images and then linking the image to the product.

Does anyone have some insights as to the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

This was relatively easy to solve. I create a reference table and simply linked product ID's to media files. If anyone wants code samples, let me know.